# AWS Cloudformation - How to pass the sns topic arn to a stack?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm creating a CloudFormation template that allows sending SNS notifications (emails) to users during creation, update, deletion, etc. from the CloudFormation stack.

How can you create a stack using the 'serverless framework' but passing it the arn of a sns topic.

I want to do something like this

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
--stack-name my-cloudformation \
--template-body file://test.yaml \
--notification-arns ${SNS_TOPIC_ARN}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your forgot to explain what did you try and what errors did you get.

Answer (score 1):

You have basically two options:

First one is using parameters in the CloudFormation template, and passing the ARN as a parameter in the call through [--parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html):

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
--stack-name my-cloudformation \
--template-body file://test.yaml \
--parameters ParameterKey=SNS_TOPIC_ARN,ParameterValue=${SNS_TOPIC_ARN}
```

The second one is, assuming the SNS topic has been also created from a CloudFormation template (recommended for IaC advantages), to store the ARN of the SNS topic (which is a CloudFormation Output) into the Parameter Store, or even directly [exporting it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html). And then retrieving its value directly from the CloudFormation template you mention. However this creates a dependency between stacks.